# using jquery scroll on ie11 issues with jittery elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, smooth-scrolling

I just encountered a strange issue on ie11. I am trying to create a fixed element that will scroll along with window scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollY=$(this).scrollTop();
    $('.myelem').css('transform', 'translateY(' + scrollY + 'px)');
});
```

I have also created a fiddle of this:

https://jsfiddle.net/fyngwnz6/1/

(This is for replicating the issue, I know this particular case could be solved with a fixed element)

The code works flawlessly with no performance issues on every browser, except ie11. When using the scrollbar 'myelem' element scrolls with just a small jitter which becomes more obvious when using the mouse wheel. However, where you can really see the issue is when using the scrollbar buttons. It seems like the render of the scrolling has to finish in order for js to track the scroll.

I saw that there were issues with ie11 and smooth scrolling, but this is not the case here. Is there any kind of solution to this? Am I missing something?

edit: although I have an answer that seems to solve the issue, actually what I am looking for is a solution to elements that have overflow:hidden applies on them and the scroll is taken from an overflown element rather than body scroll; a similar scenario can be found here:

http://www.fixedheadertable.com/

If 'fixed column' is enabled in the example, then clicking on the scrollbars shows the jerkiness in the movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like adding `height: 100%;` and `overflow: auto;` to the `html, body` elements removes the IE 11 issue:

[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fyngwnz6/10/)

**[Edit]**: Adding `margin: 0;` removes double scrollbars.

Comment: adding margin:0 and padding:0 disabled the jsfiddle extra scrollbar and seems to solve the issue but not on my specific code. Let me spend some time with this and get back to you

Comment: How would I replicate similar code when not talking about body on scroll but rather on an element scroll? This looks like a very specific hack.. ? I mean is there some kind of explanation on WHY this works?

Comment: Nice, that did the trick. If I understand you correctly, replicating this for let per say a `div` working as a container holding a child element that is supposed to be following when scrolling within? The same rules persist I would say, but I think that the `height` property is key here. And it's hard to say how one could replicate this to a page with many elements and different css attributes..

Comment: I updated the original description with an edit, if you have some time to spare please look into this

Answer (score 2):

for edge use:

```
/*Edge - works to 41.16299.402.0*/
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) 
{
    html{
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%;       
    }
    body{
        overflow: auto;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
}

/*Ie 10/11*/
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) 
{
    html{
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%;    
    }
    body{
        overflow: auto;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative
    }
}
```